# Use Field Code as File Name in Mail Merge

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I want to separate my mail merge into separate PDF files (this part is working). But the file names are being saved as a counter i.e. numbers.

```
Sub AllSectionsToSubDoc()

    Dim x               As Long
    Dim Sections        As Long
    Dim Doc             As Document

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Sections = Doc.Sections.Count
    For x = Sections - 1 To 1 Step -1
        Doc.Sections(x).Range.Copy
        Documents.Add
        ActiveDocument.Range.Paste
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs (Doc.Path & "\" & x & ".pdf")
        ActiveDocument.Close False
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

I want to extend this code so that it saves the files with file names which are NOT numbers, but are taken from one of the field codes that I specify.

For example if I specify field code «First_Name» as the file name in my VBA code, and there are 3 names - (John, Peter, Samuel) 3 files should be saved in my destination folder as John.pdf, Peter.pdf, Samuel.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from the data source, Split between commas, loop through the returned array and save each document individually.

Something like this (I haven't been able to test it).

```
Dim Value As String
Dim Names As Variant
Dim idx As Long

Value = Doc.DataSource.DataFields("First_Name").Value
Names = Split(Value, ",")

For idx = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs Doc.Path & "\" & Names(idx) & ".pdf"
Next
```

In the event where the value is a single name (no comma), the `Split()` function will return an array with a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a very simple solution to this. After creating the mail merge, I previewed the results and ran the following macro

```
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\User\Documents\folder\"
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        " C:\User\Documents\folder\" & ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Field") & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
```

and then just loop until the end